# How can I make my React-Tailwind navbar and hero elements fit the screen height?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css, tsx

I have a little problem with my current project. It is a react project with tailwind and I'm trying to style so when the users lands on the page the main elements (navbar and hero fits the whole screen height. If you know how to do it swith pure css i'm still down for it as I can convert it in tailwind.

Here is my current code :

Main element (not sure if usefull)

```
import Header from "./header";
import Hero from "./hero";

export default function OnBoardingMain() {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full min-h-full ">
            <Header />
            <Hero />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hero elemnt

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Image from "next/image";
import CtaMainButton from "./CtaMainButton";

export default function Hero() {
    const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-900 height-full top-0 left-0">
            <div className="relative isolate overflow-hidden pt-14">
                <img
                    src="image"
                    alt=""
                    className="absolute inset-0 -z-30 h-full w-full object-cover"
                />
                <div
                    className="absolute inset-x-0 -top-40 -z-10 transform-gpu overflow-hidden blur-3xl sm:-top-80"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                ></div>
                <div className="ml-4 max-w-3xl py-32 sm:py-48 lg:py-56 animate-slide-in">
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-sky-800 sm:text-6xl">
                        text
                        </h1>
                        <div className="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-6 ">
                            <CtaMainButton />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                4
                <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-400 from-30% to-transparent opacity-50 -z-20"></div>
                {/* <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-transparent opacity-80 -z-10"></div> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Header :

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Image from "next/image";
import CtaMainButton from "./CtaMainButton";

const navigation = [
    { name: "À propos", href: "#" }
];

export default function Header() {
    const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <header className="bg-white ">
            <nav
                className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8"
                aria-label="Global"
            >
                <div className="flex lg:flex-1">
                    <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                        <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
                        <img
                            className="h-8 w-auto"
                            src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="flex lg:hidden">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
                    >
                        <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                        <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                        <a
                            key={item.name}
                            href={item.href}
                            className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                        >
                            {item.name}
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
                    <CtaMainButton />
                </div>
            </nav>
            <Dialog
                as="div"
                className="lg:hidden"
                open={mobileMenuOpen}
                onClose={setMobileMenuOpen}
            >
                <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10" />
                <Dialog.Panel className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 z-10 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white px-6 py-6 sm:max-w-sm sm:ring-1 sm:ring-gray-900/10">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                            <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
                            <img
                                className="h-8 w-auto"
                                src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                                alt=""
                            />
                        </a>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="-m-2.5 rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                            onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}
                        >
                            <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                            <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-6 flow-root">
                        <div className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-500/10">
                            <div className="space-y-2 py-6">
                                {navigation.map((item) => (
                                    <a
                                        key={item.name}
                                        href={item.href}
                                        className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                                    >
                                        {item.name}
                                    </a>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                            <div className="py-6">
                                <CtaMainButton />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog.Panel>
            </Dialog>
        </header>
    );
}
```

I tried using multiple tailwind classes such as flex flex-col h-screen or h-full on multiple elements, but it never worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the main component such that it takes the height of the screen:

```html
<div className="flex flex-col w-full h-screen">
```

In the hero component, let it grow in the remaining space of the vertical flex layout not used by the header component. Remove the intermediate position parent element:

```html
<div className="bg-gray-900 grow relative pt-14">
  <img
    src="image"
    alt=""
    className="absolute inset-0 -z-30 h-full w-full object-cover"
  />
  …
```

Comment: Thanks, little correction, the bg-gray-900 would remove the image otherwise this worked !